# Баг интерфейса Gnome, переключение языков

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

*ОС - Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64*

Стоит задача - хочу в Линуксе присвоить переключение языка на  `Ctrl+ 1,2,...`(чтоб каждой цифре соответствовал свой язык).

Нашел такой способ:
Присвоить сочетаниям клавиш **консольные команды** `setxkbmap -layout <язык>`.
Но в таком случае появляется *баг*, язык переключается, но интерфейс не отслеживает это событие и **значок языка остается прежним**.

Интересно можно ли это исправить, или услышать альтернативные варианты как получить переключение языка по собственному сочетанию клавиш.

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А язык-то в результате переключается? И покажите упомянутые консольные команды.

Comment: @Roman Да, язык переключает. Используемая команда `setxkbmap -layout ua`